# Jest throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isFake')

Tags: angular, jestjs, nrwl

When I run in NX monorepo jest unit tests, In some tests (not in all test files) jest >= 28 throws the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isFake')

  150 |
  151 |   beforeEach(() => {
> 152 |     jest.useFakeTimers();
```

what is an issue in the fake-timers lib on the line:
`if (_global.Date.isFake === true) {`

When I downgraded jest to version 27.5.1 all tests are passing. Seems like issue in initialisation of the tests.

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to resolve this issue using legacy fake timers.

```
jest.useFakeTimers({ legacyFakeTimers: true });
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I just solved this by using the `fakeTimers` Jest config, like so:

```
fakeTimers: {
  enableGlobally: true,
},
```

Then I removed the individual `jest.useFakeTimers();` from my specs. This got rid of the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFake' of undefined` error.

Reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28#fake-timers

Answer (score 1):

A colleague and I figured out that `fakeAsync` and `jest.useFakeTimers` collide with each other. So this minimal example will break:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jasmine.clock().install();
        jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date('2023-12-04T00:00:00.000Z'));
    });

    afterEach(() => jasmine.clock().uninstall());

    it('should whatever', fakeAsync(() => {
        expect(42).toBe(42);
    }));

    it('2', () => {
        expect(2).toBe(2);
    });

    it('3', () => {
        expect(3).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

(mind that the first it-block will pass, every other one will fail)

Our guess is that `jest.useFakeTimers` adds the `isFake` property to the Date object, but `fakeAsync` then also tampers with the Date object, ultimately removing `isFake`.

In our case we were able to get rid of `fakeAsync` altogether, others may have to try what [h0b0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73973843/9304377) and [Chris Collins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74482566/9304377) wrote.