# How to resolve "isFake" this error in react native testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am writing test case to test react native components using react native testing library.
But getting this error before test is even run.

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isFake')`

versions:

```
 "react-test-renderer": "^18.1.0",
 "react": "18.1.0",
 "react-native": "0.70.0",
 "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.2",
 "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.1.3",
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638281/jest-throws-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-isfake